# Manage several independent Tomcat servers in one machine

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, webserver

I want to install several webapps using Tomcat but I don't want them to interfere with each other. i.e: I don't want them to work on the same tomcat server because I want to be able to restart one app's tomcat without harming the activity of another app.

I know that it's doable by installing several tomcat servers but I rahter have a central place that will run this for me.

Is there a convenient tool that lets me easily configure and manage independent tomcat servers?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a tool with UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at www.mulesoft.com/tcat. Tcat allows you to manage multiple servers, put them in server groups and configure deployments. A deployment is a bunch of apps and servers. You simply need to list the apps you want to deploy and the servers you want to deploy them on. Once done, you click a button and Tcat will push all the apps to the respective servers. Anything goes wrong, you can always rollback to the previous version of the deployment. Hope this helps. For more information around deployments, look at http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/TCAT/Deploying+Applications
Disclaimer: I manage this product.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I added some content around the answer. This was my first answer, so great to get these tips for future answers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Features), Maven plugin. It allows deployment, stop/start of a server as well as many other things.